# angular javascript automatic scrolling of element when mouse reaches border

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

I am trying to implement an angular directive (with very little luck!). That will allow the div or element to automatically scroll in the direction of the cursor reaches, when the cursor reaches the edge of said div or element. I am also curious to know if there is an open sourced module I am unaware of that will give me this desired functionality. Thanks in advance. P.S. (I do not have any code to post, as I am having difficulty beginning to write this directive.)

Comment: I would probably start by using [ngMousemove](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousemove) to get the mouse's position within your element. Monitor when it is near the edge of the element and then tell the element to scroll.